# Insert record into mysql echo table?

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

Recently I started an echo mysql table for contacts, and now I need a button to add a new contact. I tried a lot of things, and that was my result (keep in mind that everything is located at the same file):

PHP:

```
//create record
if (isset($_POST['submitc'])) {
$empresa = $_POST['empresa'];
$contato = $_POST['contato'];
$telefone = $_POST['telefone'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$sql = $conn->query("INSERT INTO Contacts (empresa, contato, email, phone) 
VALUES ('$_POST[empresa]', '$_POST[contato]', '$_POST[telefone]',      
'$_POST[email]')");

if(!$sql) {
echo ("Could not create" .mysqli_error());
  }
}
```

Form:

```
<form method=post>
  <div class='input-field'>
  <i class='material-icons prefix'>work</i>
      <input id='first_name' name='empresa' type='text' class='validate'>
      <label for='first_name'>Empresa</label>
    </div>

    <div class='input-field'>
    <i class='material-icons prefix'>account_circle</i>
      <input id='first_name' name='contato' type='text' class='validate'>
      <label for='first_name'>Contato</label>
    </div>

    <div class='input-field'>
    <i class='material-icons prefix'>phone</i>
      <input id='first_name' name='telefone' type='text' class='validate'>
      <label for='first_name'>Telefone</label>
    </div>

    <div class='input-field'>
    <i class='material-icons prefix'>email</i>
      <input id='first_name' name='email' type='text' class='validate'>
      <label for='first_name'>E-mail</label>
    </div>
  </form>

</div>
<div class='modal-footer'>
<button class='green darken-4 waves-effect waves-light btn' type='submit'       
name='submitc' value='Add'>Criar</button>
   </form>
```

As you can see in the PHP Part, I already tried a lot of things like using vars, $_POST but when I click the submit button, nothing happens, not even an error telling me something. Note that I'm trying to add value to all the 4 columns I have. What is wrong here?

(Please ignore these divs, i'm using Materialize, that's just CSS)

Comment: well for one thing, you have the ordering backwards for `email` and `phone` columns in the query where you've switched them in the values.

Comment: Also, what is that lone `</form>` doing there? You closed the form before the submit button.

Comment: @RajdeepPaul No, it is after the submit button...

Comment: @Fred-ii- Oh, yeah, thank you. Still not working tho.

Comment: @MucaP I'm talking about this: `... <label for='first_name'>E-mail</label></div></form>`, can you see this closing form tag right after the email input field? This is why your submit button is not working.

Comment: @RajdeepPaul Removed the form button, now it just creates a very long post url with all vars and weird stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you are trying to do .

```
if (isset($_POST['submitc'])) {
$empresa = $_POST['empresa'];
$contato = $_POST['contato'];
$telefone = $_POST['telefone'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$sql = "INSERT INTO Contacts (empresa, contato, email, phone) VALUES('$empresa', '$contato', '$telefone', '$email')";
$insert = $conn->query($sql);
      if ( $insert) {
          header('Location: name.php');
      }else {
          echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
      }
}

FORM REPLACED THIS 
<form method="post" action="">
  <div class='input-field'>
  <i class='material-icons prefix'>work</i>
      <input id='first_name' name='empresa' type='text' class='validate'>
      <label for='first_name'>Empresa</label>
    </div>

    <div class='input-field'>
    <i class='material-icons prefix'>account_circle</i>
      <input id='first_name' name='contato' type='text' class='validate'>
      <label for='first_name'>Contato</label>
    </div>

    <div class='input-field'>
    <i class='material-icons prefix'>phone</i>
      <input id='first_name' name='telefone' type='text' class='validate'>
      <label for='first_name'>Telefone</label>
    </div>

    <div class='input-field'>
    <i class='material-icons prefix'>email</i>
      <input id='first_name' name='email' type='text' class='validate'>
      <label for='first_name'>E-mail</label>
    </div>

<div class='modal-footer'>
<button class='green darken-4 waves-effect waves-light btn' type='submit'       
name='submitc' value='Add'>Criar</button>
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: I prefer my code to you with this it's helpful and it is working to me.

Comment: No problem @MucaP

Answer (score 1):

You have few error inside your code.

1) First of all, you have closed your form before submit button. Remove that `</form>`. Hope you will get some result.

2) Update your form starting like this `<form action="post">`.

3) Update your form posting checking like this

```
 if (!empty($_POST)) {
 echo "test<br/>";
 $empresa = $_POST['empresa'];
 $contato = $_POST['contato'];
 $telefone = $_POST['telefone'];
 $email = $_POST['email'];
 $sql = $conn->query("INSERT INTO Contacts (empresa, contato, email, phone) 
 VALUES ('$_POST[empresa]', '$_POST[contato]', '$_POST[telefone]',      
 '$_POST[email]')");

 if(!$sql) {
 echo ("Could not create" .mysqli_error());
 }
 }
```

Comment: Can you explain a little more the third?

Comment: Also you need to add your database connection info with your code

Answer (score 0):

```
//create record
if (isset($_POST['submitc'])) {
$empresa = $_POST['empresa'];
$contato = $_POST['contato'];
$telefone = $_POST['telefone'];
$email = $_POST['email'];

$sql = $conn->query("INSERT INTO `contacts`(`empresa`, `contato`, `email`, `phone`) 
VALUES('$empresa', '$contato', '$email', '$telefone');");

if(!$sql) {
echo ("Could not create" .mysqli_error());
  }
}
```

```html
<form method="post">
  <div class='input-field'>
     <i class='material-icons prefix'>work</i>
     <input id='first_name' name='empresa' type='text' class='validate'>
     <label for='first_name'>Empresa</label>
  </div>

  <div class='input-field'>
      <i class='material-icons prefix'>account_circle</i>
      <input id='first_name' name='contato' type='text' class='validate'>
      <label for='first_name'>Contato</label>
  </div>

  <div class='input-field'>
      <i class='material-icons prefix'>phone</i>
      <input id='first_name' name='telefone' type='text' class='validate'>
      <label for='first_name'>Telefone</label>
   </div>

   <div class='input-field'>
      <i class='material-icons prefix'>email</i>
      <input id='first_name' name='email' type='text' class='validate'>
      <label for='first_name'>E-mail</label>
   </div>
  
   <div class='modal-footer'>
      <button class='green darken-4 waves-effect waves-light btn' type='submit'       
name='submitc' value='Add'>Criar</button>
   </div>
</form>
```

Comment: can you insert full php script please

Comment: 168 lines long, I prefer not to

Answer (score 0):

Change to:

```
<form method="post" action="post.php">
```

where `post.php` is your POST action file and add to this file at the top

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST") 
{
.... YOU CODE ...
}
```

Comment: Ahm, but I have an echo table.